# Admin settings update updating every time home page is hit?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, admin-menu

I have created a plugin that sends an email with all orders placed that day by X o'clock to email Y.  I followed the tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-a-wordpress-plugin-part-1

On each options update, it removes all scheduled events and add new ones.  For some reason that I don't understand, the email is sending whenever someone logged in as an admin hits the home page.  Once I change and save the settings, it appears to stop.  Here is what I think is the relevant code:

```
public function options_update() {
    register_setting($this->plugin_name, $this->plugin_name, array($this, 'validate'));
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('send_woocommerce_daily_order_summary_email');
    $options = get_option($this->plugin_name);
    $timestamp = strtotime($options['send_time'] . ":00:00 " . get_option('timezone_string'));
    wp_schedule_event($timestamp, 'daily', 'send_woocommerce_daily_order_summary_email');
}
```

And where the action is added:`

```
private function define_admin_hooks() {
    $plugin_admin = new Woocommerce_Daily_Order_Summary_Email_Admin( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );

    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );

    // Add menu item
    $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_menu', $plugin_admin, 'add_plugin_admin_menu' );

    // Add Settings link to the plugin
    $plugin_basename = plugin_basename( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . $this->plugin_name . '.php' );
    $this->loader->add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . $plugin_basename, $plugin_admin, 'add_action_links' );

    // Save/Update our plugin options
    $this->loader->add_action('admin_init', $plugin_admin, 'options_update');
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why this could be happening?

Comment: You are adding an action to `admin_init` that clears and schedules an event (last line of your second code block).  [`admin_init` fires on page load in the admin section](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init), not on an options update.

Comment: Hey Andrew, that's what I thought the issue was but couldn't figure out what it should be.  I tried changing things around and making it an "options_updated" but to no avail.  I ended up stripping out the boilerplate to simplify the code.  The boilerplate was overkill for this simple of a plugin anyway.  I ended up hard-coding the options I had defined, which I don't love, but at least it works.  I'm hoping I'll be able to get back to this and find a better fix.

Comment: How did you go with this @tjfo? Did you find a better fix?

Comment: Hi @TimMalone!  I never got back to it.  There wasn't a large need to make the settings configurable, since they shouldn't be changing very often, if at all.  I might try after I finish up this next project I'm working on, just to satisfy my curiousity!

Comment: @tjfo No worries. Do let us know how you go - you can post a self-answer here if you figure it out :)

Comment: Would love to see a revised version of the code you wrote for learning purposes. Maybe someone in the community would be able to elaborate on it :)

Answer (score 1):

A much better hook to use would the the update_option_{option_name} dynamic hook, which only runs after your specific option has been updated. So something like:

```
add_action('update_option_woocommerce_email_send_time', 'send_time')

function update_send_time() {
     // Add code here to update cron job
}
```

The only problem you'll get here is that scheduling the cron job for a time earlier than the current time will trigger it to send right away. For example, if it is 3:40pm right now, and you schedule the email to be sent at 1pm, it will sent right away because that time has already passed today.  If you scheduled it for 5pm, it would wait until 5pm. Make sense?

What I'd probably do is store another value (probably using WordPress Transients) with the last date the summary email was sent, and then double check that value before sending the email out.  Once the email is sent, I'd update that transient with the current date.

References:

update_option function - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/